# React Native Geny Motion Loading issue

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native

react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.55.3

I was running via react-native run-android

The screen is always loading the app (Debugger Mode)
`127.0.0.1:8081` responding **React Native packager is running.**[image: The genymotion emulator not loading the address]

NOTE: It was sudden issue, it was working fine till yesterday. *PC is Restarted several time and also JS server using kill -9 PID

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to you have start endabling **Debug JS Remotely** while running your project.

You can **Stop Debug JS Remotely** and reload again. It will work.

Comment: Not Solved! JS Debug remotely not enabled!!

Comment: Kill the current local server and start it again with `react-native start` and then try to reload your screen.

Comment: i used **react-native run-android** Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to **Watchman**. I had a similar problem, where "react-native run-android" would run successfully, but the app would be stuck on loading in the emulator. After trying a myriad of things, what has worked for me is to disable watchman in the project directory (or uninstall) and refresh the app manually. If the app loads, then the issue is with Watchman.